# select from one table where count=1 in second table and two more conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to select transactions with cash payment and same date but only for those transactions 
which have only one payment ( so num 14 should be omitted from resultset )
So correct result is 12 and 13 only.

```
    Table2                          Table1
num  | date | data | total       num | payment | date
12      xy     abc    2.5        12      cash     xy
13      xy     cbc    2.1        13      cash     xy
14      xy     acc    2.3        14      visa     xy
19      xy     def    2.0        14      cash     xy
27      xy     fgh    1.3        19      visa     xy
                                 27       mc      xy
```

Something like this gives num 14 in result-set but 14 should be omitted.

```
SELECT num, data 
FROM Table2
WHERE num IN
(
SELECT num  FROM `Table1`
WHERE payment = 'cash'
GROUP BY `num`
HAVING ( COUNT(`num`) = 1  )
)
```

To sumarize correct answer (by tombom ):

```
 SELECT t2.num, t2.data 
 FROM Table1 as t1
 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.num = t2.num
 AND t1.date = 'xy'  
 GROUP BY t1.num
 HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(t1.payment) = 'cash'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I totally misunderstood your question. Here's how it works:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.num = t2.num AND t1.date = t2.date 
GROUP BY t1.num
HAVING  GROUP_CONCAT(t1.payment) = 'cash'
```

Comment: somehow with your select i still get results with two rows. in this case i still get num 14. isn't because payment: 'cash' is already in result without any other payments?

Comment: @phpJames Edited my answer, have a try with the updated query.

Comment: i still get rows with two payments - after changing from WHERE to AND.
to simplify we can omit date for now

Comment: @phpJames Edited my answer. This time I tested and it works. Misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: i don't see any expression to select only rows omitting cash payments with other type of payments - must be group_concat(?). but select works as expected...

Comment: Yes, group_concat does the trick. It builds a string out of all values of t1.num, since we are grouping by it.